# Detect xss from httprequest and response

Tags: http, xss

I scanned my site using a tool that detects xss vulnerabilities. As a result, the tool generates a  report that contains httprequest and response of vulnerable pages. Now my question is how this request and response can be helpful in detecting xss?

Comment: Does tool generate report for request which have xss or for the complete site??

Comment: It generates for whole website and also shows venerable pages with request-response that might be venerable to xss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request and response the reports show are not so much for detecting (since it already detected it) its more for solving it. By looking at the request you can see in what URI and what parameter the tool injected the script and by looking at the response, you can see where the injected script was reflected. With this information, you can now go to your source code and find out exactly where you are not validating properly.